# How can I get captureScreenWithName in UIAutomation working in iPhone Simulator?

Tags: iphone, automation, ios-ui-automation

I am new to iPhone Automation, and also UIAutomation introduced by iOS4.
Recently I am using UIAutomation to automate testing app on iPhone Simulator, everything goes well, until I need to take screenshots using captureScreenWithName provided by UIAutomation API. But it did not work for me, I Googled, and found that it seems this method does not work on iPhone Simulator, but works on a real device...

My question is, is there a way that I can get this method working for iPhone Simulator? By changing some settings? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Nope. I was looking for this functionality myself - and it SHOULD work but it currently does not. If you have a developer's license you can check this in the Apple Developer IOS forum.

At least we don't have to write different code for the Simulator versus the Device,

YJ

Comment: Thanks for your reply, although I have already found a workaround, but I still hope to figure out how can I get this function work in UIAutomation. I do not have a developer's license, what does the forum say about it? If it does not work for Simulator now, then in next release?

Comment: And I was driving my self mad while trying to make this work... and it's not me, it is just Apple, that implements API that works on some platforms and on others not, without putting this details into (already) shitty documentation... lol.